# Google Play In-app messaging not displaying payment declined message

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

I'm trying to implement In-app messaging to display a snackbar if a subscription has had it's payment declined.

Following the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#integrate_in-app_messaging) and adding `billingClient.showInAppMessages` doesn't seem to work. I subscribe using the `Test card, always approves` and change it to `Test card, always declines` and wait for the payment to be put in grace period, but the snackbar from the documentation does not show up even after restarting the application.

Expected result after payment has been declined and app was restarted:
[image]

In-app messaging works as I can send messages via firebase, but I am unsure if I'm missing something obvious here?

Implementation:
(This is called on app start)

```
// onCreate
billingClient = createBillingClient()
setupInAppMessaging(activity)
if (!billingClient.isReady) {
    logD { "BillingClient: Start connection..." }
    billingClient.startConnection(this)
}

fun createBillingClient() = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
    .setListener(this)
    .enablePendingPurchases()
    .build()

fun setupInAppMessaging(activity: Activity) {
    val inAppMessageParams = InAppMessageParams.newBuilder()
        .addInAppMessageCategoryToShow(InAppMessageParams.InAppMessageCategoryId.TRANSACTIONAL)
        .build()

    billingClient.showInAppMessages(activity, inAppMessageParams) { inAppMessageResult ->
        if (inAppMessageResult.responseCode == InAppMessageResult.InAppMessageResponseCode.NO_ACTION_NEEDED) {
            // The flow has finished and there is no action needed from developers.
            logD { "SUBTEST: NO_ACTION_NEEDED"}
        } else if (inAppMessageResult.responseCode == InAppMessageResult.InAppMessageResponseCode.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS_UPDATED) {
            logD { "SUBTEST: SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS_UPDATED"}
            // The subscription status changed. For example, a subscription
            // has been recovered from a suspend state. Developers should
            // expect the purchase token to be returned with this response
            // code and use the purchase token with the Google Play
            // Developer API.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has it worked at all? I believe these messages are only shown once per day so if you already saw it once, you will have to wait another 24 hours to see it again if your payment method is still failing.

Comment: It never worked. I used the test card to see if the implementation is correct, but maybe it's not testable like that? I would really like to test a feature like this before blindly shipping it to production.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this does work. I was just following one of the sample [test scenarios](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test#expandable-1) and I saw the dialog appear. It only appeared once for a given payment.

To start with I put the same sample code as yourself into my home activities onResume() and it didn't initially work because I forgot to wait for google play billing to connect. In my case there was no obvious error that that is what I'd done. I note that you do have a connection function but was just wondering if you might be in the same situation, do you need to make sure that the connection has completed before you call the show message code?